# Twitter app in android

Tags: android

I have tried many sample code connecting twitter with android app.
but nothing happen  at all.
I am blocked after getting Pin form url.
Can any give me a complete application for twitter android connection.
jeet.shri123@gmail.com
Mail the code  if any one have the code or solution  of this problem.

with thanks
Jitendra

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the correct place to ask for sample code. If you have a specific question ask it if you just want us to make your work go somewhere else please.

Answer (score 0):

Jitendra

There has been a lot of research done on the issue. Just google it out. To start up things in right direction you could use twitter4j and signpost libraries to integrate your application with twitter. Twitter has now made it mandatory for the apps connecting to twitter data to follow xauth for authentication. But please first look out twitter 4j and signpost libs